# Aggregating all Column values within a Map after groupBy in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying this all day long with a Dataframe but no luck so far. Already did it with a RDD but it isn't really readable, so this approach would be much better when it comes to code readability.

Take this initial and result DF, both the starting DF and what I would like to obtain after peforming `.groupBy()`.

```
case class SampleRow(name:String, surname:String, age:Int, city:String)
case class ResultRow(name: String, surnamesAndAges: Map[String, (Int, String)])

val df = List(
  SampleRow("Rick", "Fake", 17, "NY"),
  SampleRow("Rick", "Jordan", 18, "NY"),
  SampleRow("Sandy", "Sample", 19, "NY")
).toDF()

val resultDf = List(
  ResultRow("Rick", Map("Fake" -> (17, "NY"), "Jordan" -> (18, "NY"))),
  ResultRow("Sandy", Map("Sample" -> (19, "NY")))
).toDF()
```

What I've tried so far is performing the following `.groupBy`...

```
val resultDf = df
  .groupBy(
    Name
  )
  .agg(
    functions.map(
      selectColumn(Surname),
      functions.array(
        selectColumn(Age),
        selectColumn(City)
      )
    )
  )
```

However, the following is prompt into console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression '`surname`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
```

However, doing that would result in a single entry per surname and I would like to accumulate those in a single Map as you can see in `resultDf`. Is there an easy way to achieve this using DFs?

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve it with a single UDF to convert your data to map:

```
 val toMap = udf((keys: Seq[String], values1: Seq[String], values2: Seq[String]) => {
    keys.zip(values1.zip(values2)).toMap
  })



   val myResultDF = df.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("surname") as "surname", collect_list("age") as "age", collect_list("city") as "city").withColumn("surnamesAndAges", toMap($"surname", $"age", $"city")).drop("age", "city", "surname").show(false)
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|name |surnamesAndAges                       |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|Sandy|[Sample -> [19, NY]]                  |
|Rick |[Fake -> [17, NY], Jordan -> [18, NY]]|
+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there any way to perform .zip() without making a Tuple2 everytime? So that I can zip(), for example, 'n' values into a TupleN?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about typecasting the Dataframe to DataSet (In this case `ResultRow` you could do something like this

```scala
val grouped =df.withColumn("surnameAndAge",struct($"surname",$"age"))
.groupBy($"name")
.agg(collect_list("surnameAndAge").alias("surnamesAndAges"))
```

Then you could create a User defined function which would look like

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val arrayToMap = udf[Map[String, String], Seq[Row]] {
array => array.map { 
case Row(key: String, value: String) => (key, value) }.toMap
}
```

Now you could use a `.withColumn` and call this udf

```scala
val finalData = grouped.withColumn("surnamesAndAges",arrayToMap($"surnamesAndAges"))
```

The Dataframe would look something like this

```
finalData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, surnamesAndAges: map<string,string>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.4, you don't need to use a Spark user-defined function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_set, map_from_entries, struct}

df.withColumn("mapEntry", struct(col("surname"), struct(col("age"), col("city"))))
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(map_from_entries(collect_set("mapEntry")).as("surnameAndAges"))
```

#### Explanation

You first add a column containing a Map entry from desired columns. a Map entry is merely a `struct` containing two columns: first column is the key and the second column is the value. You can put another `struct` as the value. So here your Map entry will use column `surname` as key, and a `struct` of columns `age` and `city` as value:

```scala
struct(col("surname"), struct(col("age"), col("city")))
```

Then, you collect all the Map entries grouped by your groupBy key, which is column `name` using function `collect_set`, and you convert this list of Map entries to a Map using function `map_from_entries`

Answer (score 0):

Using spark-sql & aggregate() function:

From the given data, the result of the schema is

```
resultDf.printSchema

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- surnamesAndAges: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)


df.createOrReplaceTempView("person")

val dfr = spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select * from person ),
     t2 ( select name, map(surname,struct(age,city)) r1 from t1 ),
     t3 ( select name, collect_list(r1) r2 from t2 group by name )
     select name, aggregate(r2, cast(map() as map<string,struct<age:int,city:string>>), (acc,x) -> map_concat(acc,x) ) r3  from t3 
""")
dfr.show(false)

+-----+--------------------------------------+
|name |r3                                    |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|Rick |{Fake -> {17, NY}, Jordan -> {18, NY}}|
|Sandy|{Sample -> {19, NY}}                  |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

A round-about way is to use slice(), if you dont know how to make a map() have the above schema

```
val dfrp = spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select * from person ),
     t2 ( select name, map(surname,struct(age,city)) r1 from t1 ),
     t3 ( select name, collect_list(r1) r2 from t2 group by name )
select name, aggregate(slice(r2,2,size(r2)), r2[0] , (acc,i) -> map_concat(acc,i)) r3  from t3 """)
dfrp.show(false)
```

If you want to use the map_from_entries(), then the map in subtable-t2 should be changed to "struct". The below query works.

```
val dfp = spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select * from person ),
     t2 ( select name, struct(surname,struct(age,city)) r1 from t1 ),
     t3 ( select name, collect_list(r1) r2 from t2 group by name )
select name, map_from_entries(r2) r3  from t3 
""")
```